# Using coordinate expressions in scope transforms

Tags: tikz-pgf

Coordinate computation is powerful, especially with the `positioning` library. I would like to be able to leverage this relative calculation to compute, e.g., `xshift` and `yshift` terms for a `scope` or other sub-part of a figure, but I can't see how to easily access the components of a `coordinate` or perform other general computation in the context of applying keys.

For example,

```
…
% assume <something> has non-0 x coordinate, so offset does too - I don't want to shift horizontally at all
\coordinate[below = of <something>] (offset)
\begin{scope}[yshift = <y component of (offset)>]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
```

In this case, I'm using simple relative positioning `below = of <something>` to compute a vertical offset. I'd like to be able to use this vertical offset to shift the coordinate system of the sub-drawing in the defined scope.

I realize it's possible to pass an unadorned `(coordinate name)` directly to the 2D `shift` key, but none of the transform keys (`shift` included) seem to parse any math, even with the `calc` library. As a result, it's difficult to express anything nontrivial in-place using these keys.

What is the most straightforward way to do something like I sketched in the above code, specifying a `yshift` using the y dimension of a named `coordinate`?

Comment: `shift={(0,0|-offset)}`?

Comment: @jrk, did Qrrbrbirlbel's suggestion help you? If so, self-answers are good, so this information can be useful to future visitors. If not, please edit your question to include a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3):

Here are two methods:

- Use `\path (offset);\pgfgetlastxy{\xcoord}{\ycoord};` to get the y-dimension
- Shift by `shift = {(center|-offset)}` or `shift = {(0,0|-offset)}` if it's relative to (0,0), as suggested by @Qrrbrbirlbel

Illustrated example for both , the concentric circles are at the y-shifted position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newdimen\xcoord
\newdimen\ycoord
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (center) at (0,0) {+};
  \node[anchor=west] at (center) {Center};
  \coordinate [above right = 3cm of center] (P);
  \coordinate[below = of P] (offset);
  \node at (offset) {$\bullet$};
  \path (offset);% use the (offset) point
  \pgfgetlastxy{\xcoord}{\ycoord};% extract x,y values of last used point
  \begin{scope}[yshift = \ycoord]
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift = {(center|-offset)}]
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=4pt];
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: y-shifted circles]